# Catalogue of black holes

Tags: observational-astronomy, black-hole

Where can one find a reliable list of black holes that have been discovered/observed so far, directly or indirectly, along with their properties, like mass, spin, etc.?

Comment: Stellar, supermassive? I don't think there is a single catalogue. What does Google show you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_black_holes and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_black_holes .

Comment: @RobJeffries Catalogue of stellar black holes would work fine. A Catalog of Stellar-Mass Black Holes in X-ray Binaries is available when one does a Google search. I wanted a comprehensive list which also include those detected by other methods, like gravitational wave, etc..

Comment: The largest catalog of gravitational wave events ever assembled has been released by an international collaboration that includes Penn State researchers. Reference: “GWTC-3: Compact Binary Coalescences Observed by LIGO and Virgo During the Second Part of the Third Observing Run” by The LIGO Scientific Collaboration, the Virgo Collaboration and the KAGRA Collaboration, 5 November 2021, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology.
arXiv:2111.03606         
https://scitechdaily.com/black-holes-of-all-shapes-and-sizes-in-largest-catalog-of-gravitational-wave-events-ever-assembled/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0d92h3ro19csygf/sissa%20press%20release%20black%20holes.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_black_holes) given by @NeutronCat in a comment contains [this external link](http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/relativity/bhctable.html). This compilation by Wm. Robert Johnston has not been updated since 2004, but contains both stellar and supermassive black holes, along with some parameters (coordinates, distance, mass...).